# Rails Server dies with EAFNOSUPPORT - Windows 10, Ruby 2.4, Rails 4.2,Thin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, thin

I can run rake tasks and a console, but the development server dies a few moments after launch before I make any requests to it.

It seems like it has something to do with IPV6 based on the ::1 address but I can't find where I can do anything about that.

Any ideas?

```
C:\Rails Projects\cfhtrust>rails s
[factory_girl warning, below]
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 4.2.11 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[eventmachine warnings below]
Thin web server (v1.7.2 codename Bachmanity)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on localhost:3000, CTRL+C to stop
Exiting
C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/lib/em/pure_ruby.rb:1054:in `bind': An address incompatible with the requested protocol was used. - bind(2) for [::1]:3000 (Errno::EAFNOSUPPORT)
        from C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/lib/em/pure_ruby.rb:1054:in `start_server'
        from C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/lib/em/pure_ruby.rb:185:in `start_tcp_server'
        from C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/lib/eventmachine.rb:531:in `start_server'
        from C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/thin-1.7.2/lib/thin/backends/tcp_server.rb:16:in `connect'
        from C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/thin-1.7.2/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:63:in `block in start'
        from C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/lib/eventmachine.rb:1545:in `event_callback'
        from C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/lib/em/pure_ruby.rb:571:in `block in run_timers'
        from C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/2.4.0/set.rb:699:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/2.4.0/set.rb:699:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/lib/em/pure_ruby.rb:568:in `run_timers'
        from C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/lib/em/pure_ruby.rb:551:in `block in run'
        from C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/lib/em/pure_ruby.rb:547:in `loop'
        from C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/lib/em/pure_ruby.rb:547:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/lib/em/pure_ruby.rb:144:in `run_machine'
        from C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/lib/eventmachine.rb:195:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/thin-1.7.2/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/thin-1.7.2/lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rack-1.6.2/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:19:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rack-1.6.2/lib/rack/server.rb:286:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.11/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.11/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
        from C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.11/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.11/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
        from C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.11/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I see these warnings when I start the server, but I see the same things when I start a Rails console and then the Rails console works, so that gives me some reason to believe these are not the actual show-stoppers killing the server.

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: The factory_girl gem is deprecated. Please upgrade to factory_bot. See https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/v4.9.0/UPGRADE_FROM_FACTORY_GIRL.md for further instructions. (called from require at C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/bundler/runtime.rb:81)
C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/lib/em/pure_ruby.rb:467: warning: already initialized constant EventMachine::TimerFired
C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/lib/em/pure_ruby.rb:469: warning: already initialized constant EventMachine::ConnectionData
C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/lib/em/pure_ruby.rb:471: warning: already initialized constant EventMachine::ConnectionUnbound
C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/lib/em/pure_ruby.rb:473: warning: already initialized constant EventMachine::ConnectionAccepted
C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/lib/em/pure_ruby.rb:475: warning: already initialized constant EventMachine::ConnectionCompleted
C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/lib/em/pure_ruby.rb:477: warning: already initialized constant EventMachine::LoopbreakSignalled
C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/lib/em/pure_ruby.rb:479: warning: already initialized constant EventMachine::ConnectionNotifyReadable
C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/lib/em/pure_ruby.rb:481: warning: already initialized constant EventMachine::ConnectionNotifyWritable
C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/lib/em/pure_ruby.rb:483: warning: already initialized constant EventMachine::SslHandshakeCompleted
C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/lib/em/pure_ruby.rb:485: warning: already initialized constant EventMachine::SslVerify
C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/lib/em/pure_ruby.rb:487: warning: already initialized constant EventMachine::EM_PROTO_SSLv2
C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/lib/em/pure_ruby.rb:489: warning: already initialized constant EventMachine::EM_PROTO_SSLv3
C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/lib/em/pure_ruby.rb:491: warning: already initialized constant EventMachine::EM_PROTO_TLSv1
C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/lib/em/pure_ruby.rb:493: warning: already initialized constant EventMachine::EM_PROTO_TLSv1_1
C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/lib/em/pure_ruby.rb:495: warning: already initialized constant EventMachine::EM_PROTO_TLSv1_2
```

Comment: Switched to puma, getting different errors but at least something that gets some hits online.  Seems like it might be some kind of corporate firewall thing blocking port 3000 even when the VDI is just talking to itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the server running by switching to Puma and forcing it to IPv6 by using

```
rails s -b [::]
```

That might be a workaround instead of an answer.  I suspect there is a corporate setting or perhaps firewall issue that blocks `127.0.0.1:3000` but I never got a clear answer on that.